# Create proxy server from home modem

Tags: reverse-proxy

I live in New Delhi, India. I have virtual machines at Hetzner cloud (Finland, Helsinki). Each VM has a static IP address from Finland, Helsinki. I run some applications on the VM. How do I set the ip address of my internet connection at my home location, ac as a proxy ip of my VM ?So that:

1. The real ip from Finland is hidden
2. All requests from VM go through the ip address of my internet connection at home
3. All requests are forwarded to the VM

Answer (score 1):

This can be done by running a TCP/UDP proxy like Nginx, Traefik, HAproxy...
With this method, VMs will not be able to read the IP address of the real visitor/user from IP packets because these will be from `HOME_IP` to `VM_IP`.

In the more specific case of HTTP, one may want to run a HTTP proxy especially if one intends to do something at the HTTP level like caching or filtering.
It involves terminating the TLS tunnel with the proxy to read/modify HTTP communications. But it is still possible to have two TLS tunnels, `VM <-> home` and `home <-> remote user`. A HTTP proxy can write the visitor IP address in an HTTP header such as X-Forwarded-For or X-Real-IP, allowing the backends (the VMs) to find back this information.

Another way is connecting VMs with the home router in the same private network like a VPN. If the VMs use the VPN router as gateway, then you router becomes a "remote NAT" for your VM and can do port forwarding for theses VMs. This way, you can forward packets from home router's IP to VMs as you would with a device in your LAN. In this situation, the real user/visitor IP will be available in the packets received by the VM because only the destination is updated, not the source (for user -> home router -> VM). Inversely, the home router will do masquerading for VM -> home router -> user traffic.